# Laravel : Add notification class to send email to create new password on registration using fortify

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, fortify, laravel-fortify

My requirement is to send a new notification via email to create a new password on the new user registration using fortify.
I want to do it the same way how the reset password is done. And so far I have achieved to do it using the same sendPasswordResetNotification ie in the user model

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new SetNewUserPassword($token));
}
```

SetNewUserPassword is the new notification class to send an email to create a new password for first-time registration with a welcome message. And I am triggering it from fortify/CreateNewUser class after adding the user using

```
Password::sendResetLink(['email'=> $user->email]);
```

But with this, I am overwriting the default rest password notification email content which is in the core vendor folder.
How can I achieve both, sending different emails ie- the default one for reset password and the customized one for a set new password for new user. The reset link and everything else will be the same
Your valuable input will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that Familiar with fortify, but i do imagine that the notification works a lot like the email so create a new notification class with it's own view.

something like

```
php artisan make:mail SendResetLinkNotification
```

and then something like

```php
public function sendResetLink($token)
{
    $this->notify(new SendResetLinkNotification($token));
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I am able to send emails currently with the new class But it is also overwriting the existing reset password notification of fortify which is what I don't want to happen.